# Haskell HDBC.Sqlite3 fetchAllRows

Tags: sqlite, haskell, hdbc

Since I am an absolute Haskell beginner, but determined to conquer it, I am asking for help again.

using:

```
fetchData2 = do
  conn <- connectSqlite3 "dBase.db"
  statement <- prepare conn "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id > 0"
  execute statement []
  results <- fetchAllRows statement
  print results
```

returns:

```
[[SqlInt64 3,SqlByteString "Newco"],[SqlInt64 4,SqlByteString "Oldco"],[SqlInt64 5,SqlByteString "Mycom"],[SqlInt64 4,SqlByteString "Oldco"],[SqlInt64 5,SqlByteString "Mycom"]]
```

Is there a clever way to clean this data into `Int` and `[Char]`, in other words omitting types `SqlInt64` and `SqlByteString`.

Comment: The [HDBC documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-2.4.0.1/docs/Database-HDBC-Types.html#v:fromSql) suggests that you're looking for `fromSql`.

Comment: @Shawn: tried that. Can't find any example that works. To make matters worse: fetchRow (the one I actually need) wraps the list in a Maybe type, and returns eg. `Just [SqlInt64 3,SqlByteString "Newco"]`

Comment: To add to that: drilling down to the value (let alone when wrapped in a Maybe) must be achievable simpler than this:
`fetchData2 = do

  conn <- connectSqlite3 "dBase.db"
  statement <- prepare conn "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id > 0"
  execute statement []
  results <- fetchAllRows statement
  let first = head (results)
  let col1 = head (first)
  let showInt = fromSql col1::Int
  print (showInt)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a helper:

```
fetchRowFromSql :: Convertible SqlValue a => Statement -> IO (Maybe [a])
fetchRowFromSql = fmap (fmap (fmap fromSql)) . fetchRow
```

The implementation looks a bit daunting, but this is just because we need to drill down under the layered functors as you already noted (first `IO`, then `Maybe` and lastly `[]`). This returns something that is convertible from a `SqlValue`. There are a bunch of these defined already. See e.g. [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-2.4.0.2/docs/Database-HDBC-SqlValue.html#t:SqlValue). An example (using `-XTypeApplications`):

```
fetchRowFromSql @String :: Statement -> IO (Maybe [String])
```

I should perhaps add that the documentation mentions that `fromSql` is unsafe. Meaning that if you try to convert a sql value to an incompatible Haskell value the program will halt.

Comment: Hi Fredefox, thanks for the input. Going to give that a try. Figured that a Haskell beginner only learns by doing after having read the odd 4 books or so...

Comment: I can get it from the Maybe by using `fromJust`. That works like a charm. `fromSql` however expects a type constraint per parsed value like `fromSql VALUE::Int`. Is there a quick way parsing several columns having different types, while Haskell prefers list of a single type.

Comment: Ah yes, this is unfortunate. Perhaps this is why the authors of HDBC does not expose such a helper. Another library `sqlite-simple` solves this by defining the equivalent of your `Convertible` for tuples up to a certain length. Here's a quick-and-dirty solution for you:

`three = \(a:b:c:[]) -> (fromSql a, fromSql b, fromSql c)`

This unsafely converts a list to a triple with converted values. I'm sure you can come up with something more elegant for your use case.